I propose that the Hades-2 tag be renamed to hades-2-early-access
I propose that the hades-2 tag be renamed as hades-2-early-access. This is because the game is currently in early access, meaning some things may change, sometimes drastically (though somewhat unlikely), upon full release.
This could render questions and answers already on this site incorrect when the full game releases, even if only slightly.
Naturally, when the game is released in full, either a new tag just called hades-2 would be created, or, if nothing's changed at all, just be renamed as hades-2 (though the prior option is more likely).

I agree with this answer.  We've never done this in the past as far as I can recall.

This is unnecessary.
Even if the game changes dramatically between now and the full release, it shouldn't be tagged differently. The old answers should just be updated to reflect the new state of the game.

And if any questions pertain to outdated mechanics, they can be closed

Additionally, it's quite common for games to change drastically even after release.  Just look at Minecraft or No Man's sky.
